# How to concatenate a vector into rows of a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose numpy vector **a** and matrix **b** as below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([[3,4],[5,6]])
```

I want to concatenate vector **a** into **each row of matrix b**. The expected output is as below:

```
output=np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6]])
```

I have a working code as below:

```
output=np.array([np.concatenate((a,row)) for row in b] )
```

Is there any faster numpy function to perform such a task?
Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
output = np.zeros((2,4), int)
output[:, :2] = a    # broadcasts (2,) to (1,2) to (2,2)
output[:, 2:] = b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can broadcast `a` to the shape of `b` with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and then stack them horizontally with [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
np.hstack([np.broadcast_to(a, b.shape), b])
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did a “quick” comparison of your solution with others. As all of them are able to achieve the same result, it is important to see which one performs better.

[image]

Comment: you forgot to invite me to the party ;-) . Btw.: Nice comparison!

Comment: @RuthgerRighart there you go ;p

Comment: 2nd fastest, not bad :-)

Comment: To get representative timings in numpy, you need to try with much larger arrays

Comment: For such small array sizes, these timings don't even represent the actual difference in performance. You're just seeing the difference in overhead of the numpy functions involved. A *concatenate+for loop* won't perform as well as the other approaches on a realistic case, at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape` and `concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate((np.concatenate((a.reshape(1,2), a.reshape(1,2))), b), axis=1)
```

Or maybe better using `tile`:

```
np.concatenate((np.tile(a.reshape(1,2), (2,1)), b), axis=1)
```